# Query SQL Linked Server only pulling data from one server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I have four SQL Servers that are named in the following way:

```
dbs
dbs2
dbs3
dbs4
```

I have a table that is on dbs3 called table1 in database1. This table does not exist on the other servers. However when I run the query:

```
select * 
from dbs.database1.dbo.table1 (or any of the database servers)
```

it returns the results as if I queried the existing table on dbs3. It is like the DBMS is ignoring the 4 part nameing in the query and returning the results from table on dbs3 no matter which server I try to designate in the 4 part naming convention. Any ideas what could be going on here. The servers appear in the linked servers list.

Comment: What does `select name, data_source from sys.servers` produce?

Comment: Did you verify that the 4 linked servers actually link to different servers?

Comment: It returned:

DBS NULL
DBS2 NULL
DBS3 DBS3
DBS4 NULL

Comment: Recheck your linked server definitions, recreate them if possible. Apparently only DBS3 is configured correctly. I have never seen a linked server with an empty `data_source`, so that's quite interesting.

Comment: DBS3 is the one I am logged onto and using SSMS. Its in the linked server definition. The linked server appears to be created but all the tables listed are the same ones as on DBS3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can make changes without breaking stuff (or if it's already broken enough in your opinion), I recommend recreating your linked servers. If your linked server is another SQL Server, you can do

```
exec sp_dropserver 'dbs';
exec sp_addlinkedserver 'dbs';
```

This creates a linked server definition with the default configuration, which is appropriate for most applications (and can still be tweaked afterwards).

Comment: Recreating the linked server with the proper credentials fixed this problem. Now to get the select into working across linked servers...

Comment: @smsranger: we'll be ready for any follow-up questions about that. :-)

Comment: Surprisingly nailed it. Tables in the wind ;-) Thanks though!